# Java Table: how to make it "selection impervious"

Tags: jtable, selection

I have a table in a Java program which is read only:  and I don't need any user-selection of cells.  But, when I click on the table, an entire row will go blank, until I click on another row.  Is that a default table selection mode, and if so, how do I disable it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Answer (score 0):

YOu might be overriding the cellrenderer of the table for it to exhibit this behaviour. Make sure you set foreground and background colors. Also try making the setcellselectionenabled as true.